# Creating new matrix from the means of columns of other matrix with apply function

Tags: r

I have data matrix like the below, I want to make another matrix from it, such that the columns of new matrix is the mean of some columns of original matrix.

my matrix:

```
> A
      A1 A2 B1 B2 E3 E5 E6 E7 E8  E9
 [1,]  1 11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81  91
 [2,]  2 12 22 32 42 52 62 72 82  92
 [3,]  3 13 23 33 43 53 63 73 83  93
 [4,]  4 14 24 34 44 54 64 74 84  94
 [5,]  5 15 25 35 45 55 65 75 85  95
 [6,]  6 16 26 36 46 56 66 76 86  96
 [7,]  7 17 27 37 47 57 67 77 87  97
 [8,]  8 18 28 38 48 58 68 78 88  98
 [9,]  9 19 29 39 49 59 69 79 89  99
[10,] 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
```

My new Matrix **B**, should contain 3 columns, which first column is the *mean* of **A1,A2,** 2th columns is **mean** of **B1,B2**, 3th column is *mean* of **E3,E5,...**

How can I implement this with **apply** function

```
B<-apply(A,2, mean)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using apply you could do

```
a <- apply(d, 1, function(x) {
  by(as.vector(x), substr(names(x) , 1, 1), mean)
})
t(a)
```

The inner function splits the data by the first letters of the variable names and calculates mean values.

```
       A  B  E
 [1,]  6 26 66
 [2,]  7 27 67
 [3,]  8 28 68
 [4,]  9 29 69
 [5,] 10 30 70
 [6,] 11 31 71
 [7,] 12 32 72
 [8,] 13 33 73
 [9,] 14 34 74
[10,] 15 35 75
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
sapply(unique(substr(colnames(A),1,1)), function(x) apply(A[,grepl(x,colnames(A))],1,mean))
       A  B  E
 [1,]  6 26 66
 [2,]  7 27 67
 [3,]  8 28 68
 [4,]  9 29 69
 [5,] 10 30 70
 [6,] 11 31 71
 [7,] 12 32 72
 [8,] 13 33 73
 [9,] 14 34 74
[10,] 15 35 75
```